# Does anyone know if the TFS Office Add In will work in a Citrix environment?

Tags: azure-devops

We're rolling out the VSTS Azure solution enterprise wide and have some users that will need to use a Citrix environment.  Does anyone know if the TFS Office Addin (Office 2016) for work item updates, etc will work in a Citrix environment?

I know it installs to
C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Team Foundation Server\15.0\x86\TFSOfficeAdd-in.dll

Comment: If you mean install office on the Citrix environment (VMs), then it should work. If you mean only copy the `TFSOfficeAdd-in.dll` file to somewhere to integrate with other products, then it will not work...

Comment: Thanks.  So if we can install Office 2016 on our Citrix VM's then install the TFS Office Add on it should work fine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can try below things to use the `TFS Office Add-in` on your Citrix VMs (Windows only):

- Install Microsoft Office (Office 2016 in your scenario), then install
  Visual Studio or at least install the [Team Explorer](https://www.visualstudio.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=TeamExplorer&rel=15), the `TFS
  Office Add-in` will automatically integrate to office.
- If you don't want to install Visual Studio/Team Explorer, then you can use the TFS
  Office Integration Installer ([Download from here](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/#team-foundation-server-office-integration-2015-update-3-1)). This new
  installer just includes the Office integration component (Excel,
  Project, etc) and is therefore lighter weight. See this blog : [TFS
  Office Integration Installer](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bharry/2015/10/15/tfs-office-integration-installer/)

You can reference this blog for details : [Work with VSTS (or TFS) Work Items from Excel without installing Team Explorer](https://blog.brianrandell.com/post/work-with-vsts-or-tfs-work-items-from-excel-without-installing-team-explorer/)

If you cannot see the Team ribbon in excel, you can refer to below article for troubleshooting: [TFS-Office integration issues](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/office/tfs-office-integration-issues?view=vsts)